# Can this R function for calculating a Z-normalization without look-ahead bias be simplified?

Tags: r

I am new to R, I am facing some beginner issues:

I have the vector ts which is the daily ratio of a currency pair. I now want to calculate the z-normalization (?). It seems the function in R would look like this:

```
znorm <- function(ts){
        ts.mean <- mean(ts)
        ts.dev <- sd(ts)
        (ts - ts.mean)/ts.dev
    }
```

and I can use it to get the vector like this:

```
tsResult <- znorm(ts)
```

This is the first thing I dont really understand: the function does not seem to return anything, but creating a new vector with manipulating the given ts all at once. If someone could addtionally explain this or point me to ressources that would be great.

Anyway, my main problem was the following: The returned result included some look ahead bias, so I created my own zNorm function (which returns a 2-dimensional data frame) with a window parameter:

```
znormNew <- function(ts, window) {
        i = as.integer(0)
        df = data.frame(Count=integer(), RatioN=double())
        
        for(val in ts)
        {
            ratioN = as.integer(0)
            i = i + 1
            if(i >= window) {
                tsnew = ts[(i-window + 1):i]
                mean <- mean(tsnew)
                dev <- sd(tsnew)
                ratioN = (tail(tsnew, n=1) - mean)/dev
                #print(ratioN)
            }
            
            #print(cat(i , " -- " , ratioN))
            df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(i, ratioN)
        }
        
        return (df)
    }
```

I struggeled a lot to work this out but I think it is correct from a logical point of view.

But I think this can be simplified a lot with some deeper R knowledge. I tried to use mutate with the row_number function to make it a one-liner but that did not work because it seems row_number within mutate is a vector (and not as I assumed the respective single row_number line an index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, a function without an explicit `return` statement will return the last action, i.e. `(ts - ts.mean)/ts.dev` in znorm.

With the second function if I understand your logic correctly, for each row you want to get the zscore for that row vs a certain lookback period. The zoo package has a `rollapply` function. Note: the `scale` function that's passed into `rollapply` is base R's equivalent of your znorm. This will also return the zscores for every row in your lookback period, so the `[, window]` is to make sure to only choose the last row.

```
library(zoo)

ts <- data.frame(date = as.Date('2020-01-01') + seq(1, 20),
                 value = runif(20, min=0, max=10))
window <- 7
ts$zscore <- 0

ts$zscore[window:nrow(ts)] <- rollapply(ts$value, window, by = 1, scale)[, window]
ts


         date     value     zscore
1  2020-01-02 9.0507883  0.0000000
2  2020-01-03 2.6528930  0.0000000
3  2020-01-04 5.5656708  0.0000000
4  2020-01-05 6.9355550  0.0000000
5  2020-01-06 6.2717404  0.0000000
6  2020-01-07 9.2230508  0.0000000
7  2020-01-08 3.6954983 -1.0073333
8  2020-01-09 8.3742060  0.9598646
9  2020-01-10 1.5648625 -1.6539315
10 2020-01-11 7.4289812  0.4505279
11 2020-01-12 7.5813476  0.4659747
12 2020-01-13 3.6039318 -0.7940229
13 2020-01-14 1.9399534 -1.0337345
14 2020-01-15 6.9610210  0.5576006
15 2020-01-16 1.1036055 -1.0962716
16 2020-01-17 3.3193377 -0.4570875
17 2020-01-18 6.0283668  0.6615867
18 2020-01-19 6.9119067  1.1092511
19 2020-01-20 0.7370787 -1.1398406
20 2020-01-21 4.9342164  0.2478307
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to complete this task using "matrix" and "apply" function.
As I know, using matrix operation should be faster than looping.

```
znormNew <- function(ts, window) {
m<-matrix(c(rep(ts,length(ts)),rep(0,length(ts))),ncol=length(ts)+1,byrow=TRUE)
d<-m[(1:length(ts))<=(length(ts)-window)+1,][,1:window]
mean_ts<-apply(d,1,mean)
mean_sd<-apply(d,1,sd)
RatioN<-(d[,window]-mean_ts)/mean_sd
data.frame(window:length(ts), RatioN)
}
```